# Is there a way to retrieve a single block from a flowdocument by index?

Tags: c#, block, flowdocument

I have created a flowdocument and added a number of blocks. I now need to access the blocks based on an index value. I.E. I need the first paragraph, or the second paragraph.

How can I get a specific block given an index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to resolve this issue.

First, I created a list for the blocks

```
List<Block> Pblocks = new List<Block>();
Pblocks = TailoredResources_Reading_Text.Document.Blocks.ToList();
```

Then, I assigned the block to a paragraph

```
Paragraph paragraph = Pblocks[1] as Paragraph;
```

Finally, using a run to get the first inline via a list

```
Run sText = paragraph.Inlines.ToList()[0] as Run;
```